# manage_posts_custom_column, showing serial number using increment in loop

Tags: plugin-development, wp-query, columns

I know that [manage_posts_custom_column](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/manage_posts_custom_column), is used to add or remove custom columns to the custom post type page. The function `kiran_custom_column_content` which is hooked to the function is called as a loop for all the posts on the page. Now I want to show the post numbers in serial under the number column. So, how can I do that? If it is a while loop, may be I could have set a variable to 0 and then increment it. But how can I set a variable outside the function and increment it each time the function is called. I have tried to declare a variable globally and then increment it inside the function. But it is not working.

```
add_action( 'manage_sponsor_posts_custom_column', 'kiran_custom_column_content', 10, 2 );

global $postNumber;
$postNumber = 1;

function kiran_custom_column_content( $column, $post_id ) {

    switch ( $column ){
        case 'number':
        echo $postNumber;
        break;

        case 'carousel':
        echo 'Carousel';    
        break;
    }
 $postNumber++;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code will add an Index value to each post which is determined by `$wp_query->current_post`, the number of posts per page, and the current page being viewed.

```
add_filter( 'manage_posts_columns', 'wpse240648_manage_posts_columns_index');
function wpse240648_manage_posts_columns_index($columns) {
    $columns['index'] = __( 'Index', 'your-text-domain' );
    return $columns;
}

add_action( 'manage_posts_custom_column',  'wpse240648_manage_posts_custom_column_index', 10, 3 );
function wpse240648_manage_posts_custom_column_index( $column, $post_id ) {

    if ( 'index' == $column ) {
        global $wp_query;
        // This line is needed to set up the query so that $wp_query->current_post works.
        $wp_query->the_post();

        $page_number = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 0;

        if ( $page_number > 1 ) {
            $current_index = ( $page_number * $wp_query->query_vars['posts_per_page'] ) - $wp_query->query_vars['posts_per_page'];
        } else {
            $current_index = 0;
        }

        echo esc_html( $wp_query->current_post + 1 + $current_index );      
    }
}
```

This code can be adapted for to work for other post types by changing the hook names appropriately:

```
manage_{$post_type}_posts_columns
manage_{$post_type}_posts_custom_column
```

Comment: You got it Kiran, take care!